# Validity to the saying that 3 shidduchim guarantee a place in olam haba?

Tags: shidduchim-dating, olam-haba-world-to-come

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20376/guaranteed-olam-haba) discusses the idea that certain practices (e.g., saying *ashrei yoshvei* [[Tehilim 145](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e5.htm)] three times a day) guarantees a place in olam haba.

One common saying is that **facilitating 3 shidduchim (matches between husband and wife) guarantees a place in olam haba**?

It is often heard but I didn’t find any sources supporting it.

Any validity to this saying or is it folklore?

Comment: https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%9F/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [Rabbi Yuval Sherlo](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=85329) and [Rabbi Shelomo Aviner](http://havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=144&page=3) do not know of a source for this popular idea, so I think it is safe to say that there isn't one. 
Of course, it is a great deed (some say it can be considered as going in Hashem's ways, as the *midrash* tells us that He sits up above and [*mezaveg zivugim*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%93)).