# Source of saying that 3 Shidduchim guarantees a place in olam haba

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, shidduchim-dating

My question is related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67484/validity-to-the-saying-that-3-shidduchim-guarantee-a-place-in-olam-haba). It seems that there is no textual source for this idea. I was wondering anyone knows or can make a guess as to when and how this idea developed?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Natan and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @rosends Seems that it's the next step: After having deduced that there is no ancient source, the question is from where this idea *did* come from.

Comment: May be corrupted from Ashrei.